# Exchange Web Service. Appointment Sensitivity

Tags: exchangewebservices

I can read the sensitivity of an appointment with its corresponding property.

The Problem is, it just returns "Normal" or "Private". 
But the appointment can actually be set also to Confidential / Personal in the Properties window. But no matter what I set there, the appointment has always "Normal" except when I set it to Private.

[image: confidential]  --> appointment.Sensitivity = Sensitivity.Normal ???

This is how I read the appointment:

```
var smtpAddress ="mailboxesemail"
var calendarItems = new List<CalendarItem>();
var service = service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
service.Url = new Uri("https://EWSServerName/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials);
service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "RightToImpersonateaccount");
var cv = new CalendarView(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
cv.Traversal = ItemTraversal.Shallow;
var findresults = service.FindAppointments(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, cv)
var items = findresults.Cast<Item>().ToList();
var propertiesToLoad = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties) { RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text };
service.LoadPropertiesForItems(items, propertiesToLoad)
foreach (Appointment appointment in items)
{
   var item = new CalendarItem();//Own class
  item.Sensitivity = appointment.Sensitivity.ToString(); **<-- This is always normal, except when set to Private**
}
```

There must be a way to read it. Because the Sensitivity is shown correctly on Outlook.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can use the Extended Property rather then the strongly typed property which should reflect the property value. eg

```
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_SENSITIVITY = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x0036, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
        var propertiesToLoad = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties) { RequestedBodyType = Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BodyType.Text };
        propertiesToLoad.Add(PR_SENSITIVITY);
        service.LoadPropertiesForItems(items, propertiesToLoad);
        foreach (Appointment aptval in items)
        {
            Int32 SensVal = 0;
            if (aptval.TryGetProperty(PR_SENSITIVITY, out SensVal))
            {
                switch(SensVal){
                    case 0 : Console.WriteLine("SENSITIVITY_NONE");
                        break;
                    case 1 : Console.WriteLine("SENSITIVITY_PERSONAL");
                        break;
                    case 2 : Console.WriteLine("SENSITIVITY_PRIVATE");
                        break;
                    case 3 : Console.WriteLine("SENSITIVITY_COMPANY_CONFIDENTIAL");
                        break;
                }
            }               
        }
```

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thanks for your effort. It turned out it was our IT-Guys that always had that flag overwritten.